# Bitcoin rawtransaction fee

Tags: bitcoin, rpc, json-rpc

Создаю raw транзакцию `createrawtransaction` (указываю необходимые транзакции, выходы, куда и сколько отправлять), затем указываю комиссию для майнеров `fundrawtransaction`. Но когда начинаю проверять или подписываю и отправляю, комиссия становится больше....
С чем это связано?

Comment: А разве вы не можете сразу создать транзакцию с правильной комиссией при помощи одной только `createrawtransaction` ?

Comment: @Zergatul Вот думаю если не найду ответа так и делать, но это добавляет слишком много дополнительной логики (пересылка оставшихся монет на свои кошельки с транзакций и тд, когда есть `fundrawtransaction`) Могу сам предположить что разницу, которую я вижу в комиссиях зависит от размера. Но это не точно и хотелось бы услышать точный ответ

Comment: Да, вполне логично, сейчас единица измерения комиссии это комиссия/байт данных.

Comment: Но вопрос почему она повышается +/- в 1.5 раза от указанной комиссии и как это пресечь

Comment: Я давно уже не работал с клиентом, может чего-то не понимаю, но судя по документации, `fundrawtransaction` не предназначена для установки комиссии, если вы указали входы вручную. Без примеров сложно сказать, в чем проблема